# Python: Extracting Information from Parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I currently have 10 people, lettered `A` through `K`. Each of their scores are inserted after a player's name, like `A(12)` or `F(99)`.

For example, my current soccer team list is as such:

```
A(14)B(12)C(9)D(16)E(14)F(23)G(25)H(12)I(3)JK(14).
```

In this example, `J` has no points. (As you can tell, I hasn't practiced much. In case you can see this, Jeff, practice more. That's you. :D)

Extract the info from this list into a new list

```
scores=['A', 14, 'B', 12, 'C', 9, ...]
```

Now, print, from highest to lowest, the scores, and print (Gold) after the first, (Silver) after the second, and (Bronze) after the third, as such. Scores that are the same can be printed in any order.

```
G: 25 (Gold)
F: 23 (Silver)
D: 16 (Bronze)
A: 14 
E: 14
etc.
```

Thanks, and if this post wasn't helpful, please inform me onto how I could improve.

I have currently tried

```
>>> re.split("[()]", 'A(14)B(12)C(9)D(16)E(14)F(23)G(25)H(12)I(3)JK(14)')
```

Which gives me

```
['A', '14', 'B', '12', 'C', '9', 'D', '16', 'E', '14', 'F', '23', 'G', '25', 'H', '12', 'I', '3', 'JK', '14', '']
```

I like this, however, the `JK` are together. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please add your attempt at a solution ... this is not a homework service,  we expect you to have made an effort first

Comment: This is really multiple problems. The first (and most involved, depending on your perspective) is the extraction of the scores from the text data. The manipulation o the scores after that is a separate thing.

Comment: `re.split("[()]",my_text)` may help with the first part ... or it may not ...

Comment: To Strikeskids, I have tried exactly what Joran Beasley recommended :)

Comment: And no, I have not copy and pasted the homework. This is not homework!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different regular expression, one that provides you with a separate `(name, count)` pair:

```
import re

re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?:\((\d+)\))?', inputtext)
```

This looks for a letter in the range `A-Z` (leaving room for expansion), *optionally* (`(?:..)?`) followed by a number in parethenses (`\(` and `\)` are literal parentheses, `\d+` is 1 or more digits).

`re.findall()` produces a list of all matches in the string, each a tuple of the two groups in the pattern (each of the `(...)` enclosed patterns), so the letter followed by the score (or an empty string, for `J`):

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = 'A(14)B(12)C(9)D(16)E(14)F(23)G(25)H(12)I(3)JK(14).'
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?:\((\d+)\))?', inputtext)
[('A', '14'), ('B', '12'), ('C', '9'), ('D', '16'), ('E', '14'), ('F', '23'), ('G', '25'), ('H', '12'), ('I', '3'), ('J', ''), ('K', '14')]
```

These pairs are far more practical than an arbitrary mix of letters and digits in one flat list; your numbers are now paired with your letters intead.

Each pair can then be used to feed into a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which can facilitate the sorting for you:

```
from collections import Counter

points = Counter({name: int(count or 0) 
                  for name, count in re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?:\((\d+)\))?', inputtext)})
```

Next, a mapping to give out ranks:

```
ranks = {0: '(Gold)', 1: '(Silver)', 2: '(Bronze)'}
```

and finally a loop over [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) for a descending sort by count, together with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to provide the rankings:

```
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(points.most_common()):
    print '{}: {} {}'.format(name, score, ranks.get(i, ''))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inputtext = 'A(14)B(12)C(9)D(16)E(14)F(23)G(25)H(12)I(3)JK(14).'
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?:\((\d+)\))?', inputtext)
[('A', '14'), ('B', '12'), ('C', '9'), ('D', '16'), ('E', '14'), ('F', '23'), ('G', '25'), ('H', '12'), ('I', '3'), ('J', ''), ('K', '14')]
>>> points = Counter({name: int(count or 0) 
...                   for name, count in re.findall(r'([A-Z])(?:\((\d+)\))?', inputtext)})
>>> points
Counter({'G': 25, 'F': 23, 'D': 16, 'A': 14, 'E': 14, 'K': 14, 'B': 12, 'H': 12, 'C': 9, 'I': 3, 'J': 0})
>>> ranks = {0: '(Gold)', 1: '(Silver)', 2: '(Bronze)'}
>>> for i, (name, score) in enumerate(points.most_common()):
...     print '{}: {} {}'.format(name, score, ranks.get(i, ''))
... 
G: 25 (Gold)
F: 23 (Silver)
D: 16 (Bronze)
A: 14 
E: 14 
K: 14 
B: 12 
H: 12 
C: 9 
I: 3 
J: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `JK()` to `J(0)K()` like this. It uses positive look ahead. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
inputtext = 'A(14)B(12)C(9)D(16)E(14)F(23)G(25)H(12)I(3)JK(14).'
inputtext = re.sub(r"([A-Z])(?=[^(])", r"\1(0)", inputtext)
```

Also you can delete `J` itself like this.

```
inputtext = re.sub(r"([A-Z])(?=[^(])", r"", inputtext)
```

OK. Then you can do as you like.